# File ended while scanning use of \@new l@bel

Tags: chapters

I've been running into this weird issue using TeXShop. Whenever I compile LaTeX and get an error, the output tells me where it is. So I fix it ... and recompile. But then I get this:

File ended while scanning use of \@new l@bel

According to the discussion [here](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/Non-Recovery-from-Error-td6097784.html), I can fix this temporarily by trashing the aux file and recompiling. But that's not an optimal situation because then every time I make a tiny error, I have to re-trash my aux file before getting the compilation to proceed smoothly.

By moving my `\end{document}` code, I was able to locate the problem in my document:

```
% [Other text up here...]
\vspace{10 pt}
\noindent \textbf{My Thoughts}: Well, that was interesting.

% This part is the problem!
\chapter{Multivariable Calculus}
\label{2chapter:2}

\textbf{General Idea}: This is the study of [...]
% [Other text down here...]
```

But I can't figure out why this label is giving me the problem. I put `\end{document}` directly under this, tried to make a random error (I put a $ by itself), then deleted it, and came up with the error in the title. If I put `\end{document}` above this text and repeat the process of putting a $ by itself, I can delete it and compile LaTeX normally.

In fact, I also tried this trick with `\end{document}` at its normal spot. If I put that dollar sign above the line with 'Multivariable Calculus' it works as expected (i.e. error upon compiling, but works fine after I delete it), but if the dollar sign is below that line,  I compile (get an error) and upon deleting that sign I get the error again (file ended while scanning, etc.)!

Here's the final few lines of the aux file that got created when I saw this error. I'm convinced that the problem is with the label here, or with the label assigned to the previous chapter (Single Variable Calculus).

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {12}Operating Systems}{29} {chapter.12}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{1chapter:12}{{12}{29}{Operating Systems\relax }{chapter.12}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{II\hspace  {1em}Mathematics}{31}{part.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {13}Single Variable Calculus}{33}{chapter.13}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{2cha
```

What's confusing, though, is that all these labels are quite similar. I'm writing a book and I have formatted it so there would be a bunch of chapters, and each chapter gets a label where the label name is `Xchapter:Y` where X is the "part" number (2 in this case, which corresponds to "Mathematics"), and Y is the numbering of that chapter within that part (Y=2 here, so the Multivariable Calculus chapter is the second chapter in its part). Is there a problem with the way I'm labeling things?

In case this is helpful, here's part of the preamble (my preamble is about 100 lines long, but I commented out most of it and it doesn't seem to be giving me problems).

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,url,enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
```

Let me know if there's anything else you would need to understand this. I'm new here and not sure how much information is too much, and this post is already getting long enough as it is.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I've managed to trim down the document considerably. If you copy and paste the following text, and experiment with creating random errors before and after the Multivariable Calculus text, you should see some 'file ended while scanning ...'

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,url,enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\title{Important Stuff}
\author{Your name here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\vspace*{2 cm}
\textbf{\huge{Contents}}
\vspace{2 cm}
\toccontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\part{Computer Science}
\label{part:1}

\chapter{Introduction to Computer Science}
\label{1chapter:1}

\chapter{Data Structures and Advanced Programming}
\label{1chapter:2}

\chapter{Computer Organization}
\label{1chapter:3}

\chapter{Algorithm Design and Analysis}
\label{1chapter:4}

\chapter{Principles of Programming Languages}
\label{1chapter:5}

\chapter{Computer Graphics}
\label{1chapter:6}

\chapter{Theory of Computation}
\label{1chapter:7}

\chapter{Machine Learning}
\label{1chapter:8}

\chapter{Artificial Intelligence}
\label{1chapter:9}

\chapter{Compiler Design}
\label{1chapter:10}

\chapter{Distributed Systems}
\label{1chapter:11}

\chapter{Operating Systems}
\label{1chapter:12}


\part{Mathematics}

\chapter{Single Variable Calculus}
\label{2chapter:1}

\chapter{Multivariable Calculus}
\label{2chapter:2}

\chapter{Linear Algebra}
\label{2chapter:3}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Do you have recommendations on how to better create a minimum working example? This document has three 'parts' to it, with each part having about 10 or so chapters. I think the chapters after the first part are causing the trouble. (Or is that not what you meant?)

Comment: @TakeS: It is obvious that your `.aux` is truncated prematurely during an erroneous compilation. As such, `\newlabel` is not fully written (out has the form `\newlabel{<label>}{{<1>}{<2>}{<3>}{<4>}{<5>}}` since you're loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)), but how/why? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) is something that can be replicated. Understandably this is difficult when working with a very large document. However, always try and put yourself in the shoes of the community. We want to be able to copy-and-paste the code and see what's happening.

Comment: Are you able to trim things down from both sides? For example, move `\end{document}` upwards (like you've been doing) but also move `\begin{document}` downwards. This would minimize the scope of the problem, and perhaps allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, trimmed it up a bit and edited the post. I suspect the problem now is with either (a) the number of chapters in section 1, or (2) the use of a section before part 1. But please let me know what you think.

Comment: `\newlabel{2cha` is clearly wrong, Just delete the `.aux` file and everything should be OK.

Comment: @TakeS -- in your question, you say "experiment with creating random errors before and after the Multivariable Calculus text,". i think that this is the source of the problem -- when one of these "random errors" occurs, the `.aux` file isn't terminated properly.  so, as david carlisle suggests, delete the `.aux` file.  then clean up errors that you know about.  repeat these two steps until the "first order" errors are obliterated, and your "final" `.aux` file should be good.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and barbara beeton, if I delete the .aux file, all is good ... until I happen to cause another error in LaTeX. Then instead of finding that error, fixing it, and recompiling, I have to first delete that .aux file again, fix the text, and then recompile.

Comment: Either you or your editor, when an error occurs are abruptly killing Tex while it is writing the command to the aux file so it ends up with a corrupt aux file. As the aux file is read in at the start of the next run that just generates more errors until you delete it. It should (almost always) be possible to quit tex after an error without doing that

Comment: Following David's comment, it would be useful if you can show us what you use to invoke TeX from your editor/command line, and perhaps how it is killed.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I open TeXShop and use command-T to typeset. I don't use it from the command line on my Mac.

Comment: I've tried the example here, and as I'd expect see no issues. There must be more going on: without the detail we really can't help further. What happens if you delete all auxiliary files and run `pdflatex` on your file from the Command Line/Terminal?

Comment: @TakeS I'm having the same problem using TexShop on my Mac - whenever I make an error I have to delete the aux file before I can compile again